# Font family not rendering while converting from html to pdf

Tags: css, angular, html, pdf, fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Museo;
    src: url('../../../assets/fonts/comicsans.ttf'); 
}
.font{
    font-family: Museo;
}

@media print {
    span.font{
        font-family: Museo;
    }
}
```

font-family for fonts supported by Google is rendered both in HTML and PDF but  the ones for which font files are provided in the above format render only in HTML.

It is not working using windows.print(); to convert HTML to PDF

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not the fact that in your print media query you only target spans with class of font?

Comment: Yes I have declared font class in span tag and I want that should reflect for that same tag.